# Programming RGB LED's with Arduino

Tags: arduino, rgb, led

we are trying to code an RGB LED strip that has digital input using the arduino UNO.  Our code verifies, but when we upload we get a lot of "Invalid library found in ..."

We are just trying to upload sample code off of instructables, and this is what it looks like:

```
/*  Arduino Tutorial - How to use an RGB LED Strip
  Dev: Michalis Vasilakis // Date 3/6/2016 // Ver 1.0
  Info: www.ardumotive.com                */

//Library
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

//Constants
const int dinPin = 4;    // Din pin to Arduino pin 4
const int numOfLeds = 8; // Number of leds

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(numOfLeds, dinPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// Color takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
// e.g. White = (255,255,255), Red = (255,0,0);
int red = 255;    //Value from 0(led-off) to 255(). 
int green = 00; 
int blue = 0;


void setup() {
  pixels.begin(); // Initializes the NeoPixel library
  pixels.setBrightness(80); // Value from 0 to 100%
}

void loop() {
  // For a set of NeoPixels the first NeoPixel is 0, second is 1, all the way up to the count of pixels minus one.
  for(int i=0;i<numOfLeds;i++){
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(red,green,blue)); 
    pixels.show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.
    delay(10);   // Delay for a period of time to change the next led
  }
}
```

Our LED's arent lighting up and we have updated all libraries, our IDE is version 1.8.1, and our board and still nothing.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: That code appears to rely on the Adafruit_NeoPixel library.  Have you added that library to your Arduino IDE?  https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/arduino-library-installation

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yes, we downloaded the library through the IDE

Comment: if it compiles, then the _"Invalid library found in ..."_ message is not germane and can be ignored.